# How to Update the Field value with the default value for Whole Index in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 6.x. I created a field 'abc' and currently I have 10 records in my Index. I want to update a value '1' to all the records at single time.  What will be the preferred approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Update by Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html). Here is the example:

```
POST my_index/my_type/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.my_field = '1'",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you the comment. Its not worked when i pass the my_type and i removed the type Its worked for me.</br>POST my_index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.my_field = '1'",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}

Comment: @Nani It strange. It should work with type too. Anyway glad to help.